# How to build Wonder/WebObjects project into single WAR file?

Tags: java, webobjects

Hello I have Wonder Project and I don't know how to build it into one single WAR file that will include all the libraries. Can somebody advise me on that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using [WOLips](http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/display/WOL/Home) (the WebObjects Eclipse plug-in), you want to right-click on the top-level of your project in the WO Explorer tab, select Properties > WOLips Deployment and check Servlet Deployment. In the bottom panel, Embed Frameworks, check everything. Finally, run the `build` target in `build.xml`, and Ant will generate a WAR ready to go, with all frameworks embedded. This is explained in more detail on the [Project Wonder Wiki](http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/display/WONDER/Servlet+Deployment+Setup).